# screen not showing widgets

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

my main file . plz teach me what is my mistake, i used screenmanager to navigate between the 2 screen,
what is problem in my program? it irritating me for past 2 days. while using KIVY it is working , but mixing with kivymd and kivy it just showing black screen without the widgets i added.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen




class login_window(Screen):
    pass


class create_acc_window(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root=Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style='Dark'


if __name__ =='__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
    enter code herefrom kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen




class login_window(Screen):
    pass


class create_acc_window(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root=Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style='Dark'


if __name__ =='__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen




class login_window(Screen):
    pass


class create_acc_window(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.root=Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style='Dark'


if __name__ =='__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

my kv language file is

```
<WindowManager>:
    login_window:
    crate_acc_window:
    current: 'loginscreen'

<login_window>:
    name : 'loginscreen'
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text:'UserName'
            size_hint_x:None
            size:(180,0)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            icon_left:'email'


        MDTextFieldRound:
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
            hint_text:'Password'
            size_hint_x: None
            size: (180,0)
            icon_left:'key-variant'

        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: 'Log in'
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.3}
            on_release: app.root.current='secondscreen'
<create_acc_window>:
    name: 'secondscreen'
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDTextField:
            mode:'rectangle'
            hint_text:'First Name'
            size_hint_x:None
            size:(150,0)
            pos_hint:{'left':0.4,'center_y':0.6}

        MDTextField:
            mode:'rectangle'
            hint_text:'Last Name'
            size_hint_x:None
            size:(150,0)
            pos_hint:{'right':0.4,'center_y':0.6}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text: 'Email'
            size_hint_x:None
            icon_left:'Email'
            size:(180,0)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text: 'Password'
            size_hint_x:None
            size:(180,0)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        MDTextFieldRound:
            hint_text: 'Renter-Password'
            size_hint_x:None
            size:(180,0)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        MDRoundFlatIconButton:
            text: 'Create'
            on_release: app.root.current='loginscreen'
```

the output just rendering screen . not showing the widget. plz help me to solve it
plz.. im stucking here for 2 days. sorry, for my  bad english.

Answer (score 0):

The `build()` method of your `App` is supposed to return the root of your GUI, but your `build()` method returns `None`. Try changing it to:

```
class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("my.kv")
        self.theme_cls.theme_style='Dark'
        return WindowManager()
```

Since your `kv` file does not contain a root (a rule not enclosed in`<>`), the `load_file()` method returns `None`.